# jQuery .show('slide') without using jQuery UI

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was wondering if there's a jQuery function that do the same effect as this code without using jQuery UI?

```
$(selector).show('slide', { direction: 'right' }, 300);
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Jwkw6/1/

Comment: @MelanciaUK, my question is about how to achieve the effect of the code i gave above WITHOUT using jQuery UI.

Answer (score 3):

No, but you can `animate` the `element` as you wish.

[Here's a great tutorial](http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/02/slide-elements-in-different-directions)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick plugin that I came up with. It basically animates the `width` and `opacity` properties:

```
$.fn.slideRight = function(duration, callback) {

    duration = duration || 300;

    return this.each(function() {
        var $this = $(this),
            css = getInitialStyle($this);

        $this
            .css({width: 0, display: 'block'})
            .animate(css, duration, callback);
    });

    function getInitialStyle($el){
        var css = $el.data('initialStyle');

        if(!css || !css.width || !css.opacity) {
            var isHidden = $el.is(':hidden');
            if(isHidden) $el.show();
            css = {
                width: $el.width(),
                opacity: $el.css('opacity')
            }
            if(isHidden) $el.hide();

            $el.data('initialStyle', css);
        }

        return css;            
    }
}
```

And here's the [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/K6fw4/2/).

Comment: Yes, you should animate the `margin-left` property to something similar to `'+=' + css.width`